# Best practise to load content when Ember application boots

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to load contents coming from my API when the application boots, then inject what I get into all routes and controllers to be able to access them whenever I want.

I was wondering where is the best place to do that in Ember?

- In an initializer? I've heard that it's not a good practise to use the store from there...
- In the application route? Then how can I access it from all routes and controllers? Using `this.modelFor('application')`? Is that a good practise?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if using the application route and `this.modelFor('application')` is the best or recommended way, but it works for me to load the main data there.

Comment: we've registered a `session` object (`this.register('session:main', session);`) and then injected to all the controllers (`this.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');`). We keep the information about the logged user there only though.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to load anyway, and is this through ember-data or not? Your question isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

The best place would be in the `ApplicationRoute`, you can do this in the `beforeModel` or `afterModel`/`setupController` hook as you like.  Here's a `beforeModel` example:

```
ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    beforeModel:function() {
        var self = this;

        var rsvp = Ember.RSVP.hash({
            fruits: self.store.find('fruit'),
            candies: self.store.find('candy'),
            meats: self.store.find('meats')
        }};

        rsvp.then(function(models) {
           self.controllerFor('fruits').set('model',models.fruits);
           self.controllerFor('candies').set('model',models.candies);
           self.controllerFor('meats').set('model',models.meats);
        });
    }
});
```

The `rsvp` fetches all of the models together and waits for them to precede before continuing which happens on the `then`. We then assign all the found models to the `model` property on their matching controller.

*To do this in the `afterModel` hook, it would look different.*

Comment: In my case, I need to inject the data into all my controllers and routes, how can I do that with your suggestion?

Comment: Routes don't store data; only controllers. What do you mean by inject?

Comment: I'm going to get session information from the api and store them, then I need to check those session information, in `beforeModel()` for example and redirect the user if he's not allowed to access the route.